# Homomorphism first theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove the homomorphic image of a $p-$group is a $p-$group .

I will use the first homomorphism theorem.

Let $\Bbb Z_p$ is a $p-$group, but how find the homomorphic image?

Comment: Suppose $\phi:G\to H$ is a homomorphism. $G$ is a $p$-group means that every element has order a power of $p$. So let $h\in \phi(G)$. Then we can find $g\in G$ st $\phi(g)=h$. Suppose $g$ has order $p^k$. What can you say about $h^{p^k}$?

Comment: Using the hint of @almagest, also use property of homomorphism: $\phi (g)^k=\phi(g^k)$.

Comment: @almagest  I will say $\phi(g)^{p^k}=h^{p^k}$ true?